# jQuery Mobile datepicker not adding all classes

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

After adding the jQuery Mobile datepicker to our MVC application it works fine but doesn't look right (it's transparent, the icons are missing, fonts wrong etc).

Comparing it to the demo at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/datepicker/, I can see in the debugger that some of the classes are missing in our version. For example, the demo says

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-shadow"...
```

I get

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"...
```

In this case, ui-shadow is missing; the same is true for the other elements, for example the buttons do have ui-state-default but are missing the ui-btn class, the prev/next buttons are missing everything except 'ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all' and so forth.

The datepicker is initialised after $(document).ready with "$('.datepicker').datepicker()".

The loaded styles and scripts are (debug mode)

```
<link href="/somePath/jq-mobile.1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/somePath/jquery.mobile.icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css">
<script src="/somePath/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="/somePath/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="/somePath/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/jquery-ui/1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script id="mobile-datepicker" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
```

As mentioned, functionality is not a problem, all works as expected, but obviously I'm missing something. Does anyone know why not all classes are added?

Comment: According to the [github](https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper) link you must call methods with `.date()` and not `.datepicker()`  "**Please note: this widget is called date not datepicker so when calling methods you must use $(element).date("method");**"

Comment: thanks, that was it! if you post as answer, I'll mark it accordingly

Comment: sure ^^ i'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [github](https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper) link you must call methods with `.date()` and not with `.datepicker()` this might help you.

> "Please note: this widget is called date not datepicker so when
>   calling methods you must use $(element).date("method");"**

**At the Bottom of the README